# reading .pst binary files win10

Tags: python

I have to manipulate large `.pst` files(export of outlook).I read directly pst file with the lines below using a sample `backup.pst` file

```
import binascii
i=0
with open("backup.pst", "rb") as binary_file:

    buf_size = 1024 * 1024
    binary_file.seek(0)
    couple_bytes = len(binary_file.read()) #count characters
    print ('chars=',couple_bytes)

    binary_file.seek(0)  # Go to the beginning
    lines = len(binary_file.readlines())#count lines
    print('lines=',lines)
    binary_file.seek(0)#again at the beginning
    for line in binary_file:
        i+=1
        print(i,'          ',line,'\n')
```

with python 3.6 running on idle
I get an output like this

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\Nikos-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pyfiles\binaryfile2.py 
chars= 271360
lines= 21
1            b'!BDN6\xa3\xb3\xe3SM\x17\x00\x13\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xd6\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00V\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x12\x04\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x12\x04\x00\x00\x12\x04...............
```

While display the last line (21) my computer is freeze ,ctrl+c not working and i have to stop the progr with task manager.
How i can get the reason of the troubleshoot?

Comment: Just try to print a lot in the windows command line, maybe that alone reproduces the problem? On windows output blocks  the console & program...

Comment: Your freeze in IDLE is probably because the file is too big for it to handle. By your own count the file is 270k but has only 21 linebreaks. That is going to be a challenge for any program trying to display linewrapped text. Try running the program in the command-line interpreter. Reading and decoding a .pst file is a significant challenge: in fact Microsoft recommends that you don't try. But there are docs on the structure here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615595(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: thanks for the answers.i'll try to run on commandline.